# Замена элемента в массиве char []

Tags: java

Всем привет!
В рамках обучения решаю задачку.
**Условия такие:** Написать метод, который принимает в качестве аргумента String, и в случае если символ в String повторяется (например Б*а*л*а*л*а*йк*а*), то повторяющиеся символы меняются на символ ')'. То есть буквы "а" и "л" будут заменены на ")" и получится *"Б)))))йк)"*. А все остальные символы заменяются на "(". Как итог получится *"()))))(()"*.

Для решения этой задачки я написал следующий код (не кидайте тапками я новичок):

```
    static String encode(String word){


    char [] arr = word.toCharArray();

    //search for duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){ // Bug
        for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
            if (arr[i]==arr[j]){
                arr [i] = ')';
                arr [j] = ')';
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k<arr.length;k++){
        if(!(arr[k]==')')){
            arr[k] = '(';
        }
    }

   word = new String(arr);
    return word;
}
```

и это даже частично работает, но не до конца.
Проблема в том, что когда цикл прокручивается, он меняет два символа, но если дальше в слове есть еще такой символ, он его пропускает так как те два уже были заменены и они не совпадают.
Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текущий символ по индексу `i` следует менять *после* вложенного цикла, *если* был обнаружен дубликат.  Соответственно, можно сразу установить этот символ в `(`, если символ оказался уникальным в строке.

Кроме того, если текущий символ уже установлен в `)` как дублированный, можно не проверять его во вложенном цикле, и использовать `continue`, чтобы пропустить итерацию.

```java
static String encode(String word) {

    char[] arr = word.toCharArray();

    //search for duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        char curr = arr[i];
        if (curr == ')') {
            continue; // найден предыдущий дубликат
        }
        boolean dupFound = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (curr == arr[j]) {
                arr[j] = ')';
                dupFound = true;
            }
        }
        arr[i] = dupFound ? ')' : '(';
    }

    return new String(arr);
}
```

Тест:

```
System.out.println(encode("Балалайка")); // -> ()))))(()
System.out.println(encode("Success")); // -> (())())
```

---

Если во входной строке могут попадаться символы `')'` и/или `'('`, то тогда следует использовать вспомогательный массив булевых значений для обнаружения дубликатов, и строить результирующую строку уже по значениям в этом массиве:

```java
static String encode2(String word) {
    // использовать один регистр
    char[] arr = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray(); 
    boolean[] dups = new boolean[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        char curr = arr[i];
        if (dups[i]) {
            continue; // найден предыдущий дубликат
        }
        boolean dupFound = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (curr == arr[j]) {
                dupFound = true;
                dups[j] = true;
            }
        }
        dups[i] = dupFound;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arr.length);
    
    for (boolean dup : dups) {
        sb.append(dup ? ')' : '(');
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println("'" + encode2(" ()( ") + "'"); // -> '))())'
System.out.println("'" + encode2(" ()) ") + "'"); // -> ')()))'
```

Comment: Сейчас Вам скажут про слово Success.

Comment: Да вроде всё работает, как и в вашем коде :)

Comment: Вероятно, ТС забыл упомянуть про нечувствительность к регистру.

Comment: Да всё действительно работает!:) Это я не много тупанул

Comment: Ещё небольшой вопрос. У меня проблемка с заглавной буквой. Действительно, реестр игнорируем. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Либо приводить каждый символ по отдельности в какой-то один регистр и сравнивать их `curr = Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]); ... if (curr == Character.toLowerCase(arr[j])) {...}`, либо сразу привести всё слово в определённый регистр, перед получением массива: `char[] arr = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Извините, ещё раз побеспокою :) Если в метод передать "   ()(   ", то ожидаемый результат по тестам должен быть "))))())))", а по факту выдает ")))))))))". В чем тут проблема? Уже минут 40 голову ломаю

Comment: А как из входной строки `" ()( "` длиной 5 символов (не включая кавычки) должно получиться даже не десять, а девять символов?

Comment: Извините, написал не верно. Там вот так:"    ()(   ". Там как раз 9 символов.

Comment: Смотрите обновленный ответ, там скобки обрабатываются корректно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            arr[j] = ')';
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found)
        arr[i] = ')';
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает( Со словом Success не проходит например

Comment: @Alex_Lynx проходит.

Comment: Сорри, тупанул. Да, проходит

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!